# Why can't I make multiple LookupRows in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup

On a CloudPage, I want to accomplish 3 loops.

In each loop, I want to retrieve the total number of records from a Data Extension and insert a new record.

Here is the code I came up with.

```
%%[

SET @LastName = "Jon"
SET @FirstName = "Snow"
SET @EmailAddress = "jon.snow@crowmail.com"
SET @DE = "MyDataExtension"    

FOR @i = 1 to 3 DO

    SET @DERows = LookupRows(@DE,'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress)

    OutputLine(concat("-> Rows: ",ROWCOUNT(@DERows),"<br>"))

    SET @Insert = InsertData(@DE,'Id',GUID(),'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress,'FirstName',@FirstName,'LastName',@LastName)

    OutputLine(concat("----> Records inserted: ",@Insert,"<br>"))

NEXT @i

]%%
```

It should return

```
-> Rows: 0
----> Records inserted: 1
-> Rows: 1
----> Records inserted: 1
-> Rows: 2
----> Records inserted: 1
```

But instead it returns

```
-> Rows: 0
----> Records inserted: 1
-> Rows: 0
----> Records inserted: 1
-> Rows: 0
----> Records inserted: 1
```

As if the **LookupRows** function stops working after the first time it's executed.

Same happens when I use SSJS core functions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what context?  An email or CloudPage?

Comment: The lookup rows works but the data is not inserted till the end with ampscript. I believe your use could be solved with ssjs core functions

Comment: Yeah, I think insert/upsertData functions are queued and done last in all contexts. Would welcome some official confirmation on that.

Comment: Hi, Ivan. I am seeing the same behaviors, replicating your script in a CloudPage. Having explored both AMPscript and SSJS options (including the use of an SSJS time delay withing the loop and loading the lookup data extension with 2000 rows of 'garbage' data to rule out caching), I would agree with Adam sprig that this may have to do with insert/upsertData being done last. Several members of our team have looked at it now, and we all have arrived at the conclusion that the issue isn't the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

As @EazyE stated in his comment, your solution is to utilize the SSJS Core library in order to return 'real time' row counts.

Utilizing any of the AMPscript or SSJS Platform functions, will return as you showed above. This is due to the way these are processed (now, admittedly, I am working off of assumptions and guesses, so I COULD be wrong, but I am mostly sure I am not).  Platform and AMPscript group the processes and run them in 'bulk' at the end of the operation. Meaning that All lookups will be done together and not within context of the script. And with that, the lookups that are identical will always return the same result regardless of context with inserts or deletes, etc.

The Core library function [Rows.Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.htm) seems to work outside of this process and is returned in context (which is likely part of why they take so much longer and require extra processing).

By utilizing either Rows.Retrieve in your script, you can get your 'real time' rowcount as requested.

Example below:

```js
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load('Core','1.1.1')

var LastName = "Jon"
var FirstName = "Snow"
var EmailAddress = "jon.snow@crowmail.com"
var DE = "test_de1"    

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var init = DataExtension.Init(DE);
  var filter = {Property:"EmailAddress",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:EmailAddress}
  var DERet = init.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
  Write("-> Retrieve: " + DERet.length + "<br>");

  var Insert = Platform.Function.InsertData(DE,['Id','EmailAddress','FirstName','LastName'],[GUID(),EmailAddress,FirstName,LastName])
  Write("----> Records inserted: " + Insert + "<br>")

  var DERet = init.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
  Write("-> Retrieve2: " + DERet.length + "<br>");
  Write("<br><br>")
}

</script>
```

Output:
[image]

---

**EDIT**
I was asked to verify if WSProxy would work as well, and I am happy to report that it in fact does.  See below for sample:

```js
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load('Core','1.1.1')

var LastName = "Jon"
var FirstName = "Snow"
var EmailAddress = "jon.snow@crowmail.com"
var DE = "test_de1"    

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    var cols = ["EmailAddress"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "EmailAddress",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: EmailAddress
    };

    var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + DE + "]", cols, filter);
    Write('desc: ' + Stringify(desc.Results.length) + '<br>');

    var Insert = Platform.Function.InsertData(DE,['Id','EmailAddress','FirstName','LastName'],[GUID(),EmailAddress,FirstName,LastName])
    Write("----> Records inserted: " + Insert + "<br>")

    var desc2 = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + DE + "]", cols, filter);
    Write('desc2: ' + Stringify(desc2.Results.length) + '<br><br>');
}

</script>
```

With an output of:
[image]